# DIV (footer2_container) floating out of footer container

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble generate the exact error in jsfiddle. So please bear with me.

In jsfiddle it looks exactly how I want it. However in the browser (chrome), my footer divs (footer1_container + footer2_container) seem to be pushed down inside the main "footer_container". The result on the browser is that the lower div is outside of the main "footer_container".

https://jsfiddle.net/jv3q0z7a/

```
    <div class="footercontainer">
    <div class="footer1_container">
<p class="p_footer1"><span style="color:#fa7900">Prana Yoga</span> | <span style="color:#fa7900">Hot Yoga</span> | <span style="color:#fa7900">Yoga Body Work</span> | <span style="color:#fa7900">Healing Sessions</span></p>
        </div>
    <div class="footer2_container">
        <div class="left_footer2"><p class="p_footer2">n Blvd, Flushing NY </p></div>
        <div class="right_footer2">  <p class="p_footer2">© 2016 ga - Namaste!</p> </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Flowing out of footer_container](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zPAb5.jpg)

Comment: Try this: `.footercontainer {
    overflow: auto;
}`

Comment: Didn't work. I tried inserted "overflow:auto" into the .footercontainer

Comment: It was worth a shot. What else have you tried? Provide a live link if you can, or try CodePen, something else that will give you a wider viewport to work with and better reproduce the issue.

Comment: Thanks, I just tried on CodePen, same thing as JSfiddle.

Sorry I don't have a live link. The code that is in jsfiddle is the same as what I'm using to generate the webpage in  my browser. Weird that its only not working on the browser.

Comment: You'll just have to tinker around with styles and given elements in browser then. I can only reproduce the issue when zooming out to about 75%; then removing all the absolutely declared height values on those elements resolves the issue.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'll keep trying

Comment: in `.footer2_container` can you add a small `margin-top` to separate the elements?